# Not able to connect React App with a NodeJS in Backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, server, backend

I am trying to fetch data from backend but getting error `fetchData.map is not a function`.

If can anyone explain me why `fetchData.map is not a function`

This is react code

```
    function App() {
        const [fetchData, setFetchData] = useState([]);
        useEffect(() => {
            fetch("/api")
                .then((res) => res.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    console.log(data);
                    setFetchData(data);
                });
        }, []);
        return <>{fetchData.map(data=> <div>data</div>)}</>;
    }
```

This is NodeJS code

```
    const express = require("express");
    const app = express();
    const test = require("./test.json");
    
    PORT = 3001;
    
    app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
        res.json(test);
    });
    
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server Started on ${PORT}`));
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the response from the request ? What does the log shows ?

Comment: changes  res to req getting `GET http://localhost:3000/api 500 (Internal Server Error)` in NodeJS

Comment: your fetchData is not an array, dont use map. use ```Object.keys(fetchData).map(item => fetchData[item])```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  function App() {
        // Change it to null by default
        const [fetchData, setFetchData] = useState(null);
        useEffect(() => {
            fetch("/api")
                .then((res) => res.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    console.log(data);
                    // wrap data with [] to make it iterable
                    setFetchData([data]);
                });
        }, []);

        // Check if value is present before mapping 
        return <>{fetchData?.map(data=> <div>data</div>)}</>;
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this but not working

Comment: you should check if the value is not null before you map a list 

<>{fetchData?.map(data=> <div>data</div>)}</>

Comment: Thanks now I understand how to get data from json in 3 different formats

Answer (score 1):

Because your response is object not an array.

[image]

You can use map, filter and ... for array